# How to load Microsoft.Advertising.JS in Visual Studio 2017 Cordova project?

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, uwp

i stuck at including Microsoft Advertising SDK in my Cordova project.

I do all instruction from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/install-the-microsoft-advertising-libraries

I Install via NuGet components:
1. Microsoft.Advertising.JS
2. Microsoft.Advertising.XAML
3. Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement
4. Microsoft.Services.Store.SDK
5. Winjs too

[image]

Then Documentation says "Add a reference to the Microsoft Advertising SDK"
But i dont have "Reference" node in my Solution Explorer Tree:

[image]

Then i included ad.js in index.html in :

[image]

But i still got error when starting app:
APPHOST9623: The application couldn't resolve ms-appx-web://microsoft.advertising.javascript/ad.js because of this error: 80070057.

I found something strange in .jsproj file:

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.

Please help.

Comment: For adding Microsoft Advertising SDK, you could open CordovaApp.sln file where in  the solution folder -> `Platforms` folder -> `Windows` folder, then add the nuget package.